# Incorrect functioning of routes in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

When trying to navigate from 'users' to 'users/:id' like this

```
this.router.navigate([`/users/${userId}`]);
```

or

```
this.router.navigate(['/users', userId]);
```

it stays on 'users' but url in browser bar changes to 'users/{correct_id}'

Application structure:

- dashboard (/)
- login (/login)
- users (/users)

  - users/id (/users:id)

I suspect the problem lies in my routes but unfortunately I can't find it.

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    loadChildren: (): Promise<DashboardModule> =>
        import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(
            (m: typeof import('./dashboard/dashboard.module')): DashboardModule => m.DashboardModule
        )
},
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    loadChildren: (): Promise<LoginModule> =>
        import('./login/login.module').then(
            (m: typeof import('./login/login.module')): LoginModule => m.LoginModule
        )
},
{
    path: 'users',
    component: UsersComponent,
    loadChildren: (): Promise<LoginModule> =>
        import('./users/users.module').then(
            (m: typeof import('./users/users.module')): UsersModule => m.UsersModule
        )
},
{
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
}
```

];

users-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: UsersComponent,
},
{
    path: ':id',
    component: UserProfileComponent,
},
```

];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably in the following route:

```
{
  path: 'users',
  component: UsersComponent, // <-- HERE
  loadChildren: (): Promise<LoginModule> =>
    import('./users/users.module').then(
      (m: typeof import('./users/users.module')): UsersModule => m.UsersModule)
},
```

When you assign a component to a route, when that route matches, this component will always get rendered. And if it has children, they will get rendered in the `<router-outlet>` of that `UserComponent` template.

Since you also have the `UserComponent` assign to the children root path, I guess that's not the case.

To solve it you just need to remove the component line from the `'users'` route.

```
{
  path: 'users',
  loadChildren: (): Promise<LoginModule> =>
    import('./users/users.module').then(
      (m: typeof import('./users/users.module')): UsersModule => m.UsersModule)
},
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you sir for the clarification and solution! It was indeed enough to remove that line and the navigation works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems,

1st - You have used lazy loading feature so, you don't need to load component in main route

```
{
    path: 'users',
    component: UsersComponent, // <-- REMOVE it
    loadChildren: (): Promise<LoginModule> =>
        import('./users/users.module').then(
            (m: typeof import('./users/users.module')): UsersModule => m.UsersModule
        )
},
```

2nd - Then you also need to change in user module route like,

users-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  children: [{
    path: '',
    component: UsersComponent,
  }, {
    path: ':id',
    component: UserProfileComponent
  }]
}];
```

Hope you are clear with this solution

Answer (score 1):

in your first attempt,

```
this.router.navigate([`${userId}`]);
```

you are trying to route based on a relative path, yet you don't provide the `relativeTo` property which is needed to route relative to the current path.

in your second attempt,

```
this.router.navigate([`${users/userId}`]);
```

you have few issues:

1. by not starting navigation with '/' the router thinks your'e trying to navigate relatively to the current route, which isn't the case.
2. your route string template is wrong (your'e trying to use variable  `users/userId` which is clearly not what you meant), you should change it to:

   this.router.navigate(['/users', `${userId}`]);

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issues, unfortunately after correcting them the problem did not go away, still despite changing the url to the correct view does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove component setting in `routes` array.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    ...
    {
        path: 'users',
        // component: UsersComponent,                << remove this line
        loadChildren: (): Promise<LoginModule> =>
            import('./users/users.module').then(
                (m: typeof import('./users/users.module')): UsersModule => m.UsersModule
            )
    },
    ...
];
```